# Recommended thread properties values for stresstesting with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to stresstest a site using Jmeter, right now i am using WAMP and widnows.

What would be the best stresstesting settings for this? this is a page that will have alot of users, 100k users / day+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100k users per day is not that "lot" in my opinion:

- 100 000 / 24 == 4166.67 users per hour
- 4167 / 60 == 69.44 users per minute
- 69 / 60 = 1.15 users per second

The normal way of testing the application is starting with either 1 or expected amount of virtual users and gradually increase the load until one of the following conditions is met:

- response time goes above acceptable level
- application starts consuming > 80-90% of underlying hardware resources (CPU, RAM, Disk and/or Network IO)
- application starts returning errors and the amount of errors exceeds threshold

Also I would recommend to test the following scenarios:

1. [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) - put your application under anticipated load for short period to see how does performance metrics look like
2. [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)) - determine the **maximum** amount of concurrent users that your application can handle keeping reasonable response times. You can also determine breaking point, i.e. when application starts returning errors or stops responding and whether it can recover
3. [soak test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) - basically the same as point 1, but the load should sustain for a longer period, i.e. several hours or if time allows - several days. It will help to identify memory leaks if any

Comment: number of threds indicates the nr of users? but loop count needs to be set to how many requests user make?

Comment: Each virtual user (thread) executes samplers upside down. When there are no more samplers to execute or loops to iterate - the thread will shut down. The number of loops == the number of iterations for each virtual user. You can also set loops count to `-1` (the test will run forever) and configure the desired test duration via `Scheduler - Duration (seconds)` input

Comment: Samples, is the page? one page might inlcude css,js etc, is thise files also loaded on each request?

Comment: If you configure [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` - they will also be downloaded (use it with [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)). Check out [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) for more details